# channels on logic level shifter outputs high

Tags: arduino-uno, power, esp32, voltage-level, voltage

so I have a logic level shifter which is TXS0108E ,I use it to shift the eps32 ouput volatge to 5v to be used with motor driver ,when I test it with multimeter , all the channels on the B side outputs high (5v) without connecting anything on the A side, my connection is this :
[image]

Comment: it is normal...

Comment: So how can the driver know if it is high or low if it is all the time high

Comment: an unconnected pin of the converter when powered is HIGH. the input must pull it down to change the state and that state is reflected on output.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that , thanks.